# Dynamically resize text in content box

Tags: css

I created a content box for a quote on a website, however, upon responsiveness testing the text seems to fall out of the box at the smallest scales.  Any suggestions on dynamically resizing the text?  Preferably, using CSS...

```
.applebox {
    width: auto;
    height: 85px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    padding: 20px 20px 10px;
    margin: 10px 0 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}

.applebox .col {
    width: 140px; 
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are looking for a solution that will change the `font-size` property, that should be possible via CSS3 Media-Selectors. There are selectors that allow rules to only be applied for certain screen-sizes. Read here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

If you're fine with word-wrapping, try the `word-wrap` property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Comment: yeah that makes sense.  I think a media query might be the best way to go here.  Thanks for your input.